# Creating a pie chart in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pie-chart

Hi I have the following code which creates a histogram using certain figures but I need to create another chart that is a pie.

```
m_values, m_base = np.histogram(mitotic_T, bins=15)
d_values, d_base = np.histogram(death_T, bins=15)
#evaluate the cumulative
plt.title('TPT GRAPH')
m_cumulative = np.cumsum(m_values)
d_cumulative = np.cumsum(d_values)
plt.plot(m_base[:-1], m_cumulative, c='green')
plt.plot(d_base[:-1], d_cumulative, c='red')
plt.show()
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'mitotic_T' is not defined`. Please provide a full working example (inclusing imports)!

Comment: Have you tried using the [`pie`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie) function?

Comment: Here's an [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.html).